# Why doesn't my query return any results when I add a WHERE clause?

Tags: database, sqlite, delphi

My Delphi application is connected to SQLite successfully.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ZQuery1.Close;
  ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  ZQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT Name FROM city;';
  ZQuery1.Open;

  while not ZQuery1.EOF do
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(ZQuery1.FieldValues['name']);
    ZQuery1.Next;
  end;
end;
```

The above code works fine and loads contents of field name from table city.
However,

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ZQuery1.Close;
  ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  ZQuery1.SQL.Text := 'Select name from city WHERE district = :aField';
  ZQuery1.Params.ParamByName('aField').Value := 'kabol';
  ZQuery1.Open;

  while not ZQuery1.EOF do
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(ZQuery1.FieldValues['name']);
    ZQuery1.Next;
  end;
end;
```

Surprisingly, when I add a where clause, the query returns nothing! Could anyone suggest what is wrong in my code?

Here is an image of the data in my table:
[image]

Comment: Do you have at least one row of data where `district` is `kabol`? If not, you'll have no results in your query, and therefore `ZQuery1.Eof` is true and you never enter the `while` loop.

Comment: I didn't ask if you had **data** in your table. I asked if you had at least one row where `district` is `kabol`. Change your first (working) query to `SELECT Name, District FROM City`, and the output to `Memo1.Lines.Add(ZQuery1.FieldValues['name] + #9 + ZQuery1.FieldValues['district']);`. Do you see at least one line with `kabol` in the memo?

Comment: I understood my mistake : Kabol is case sensitive!
it should have been -
     ZQuery1.Params.ParamByName('aField').Value := 'Kabol';

not -
ZQuery1.Params.ParamByName('aField').Value := 'kabol';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably don't have any data that has a `district` of `kabol`. The addition of the `WHERE` clause would then result in no rows being returned, meaning that `ZQuery1.Eof` is immediately true, and your `while not ZQuery1.Eof do` loop never gets entered.

You can check this by changing your first query (the one that works) to something like this:

```
ZQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT Name, District FROM City';
```

Then change the output to

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(ZQuery1.FieldValues['name'] + #9 +
                ZQuery1.FieldValues['district']);
```

If you don't see at least one line in the memo that contains `kabol` in the rightmost column, you don't have any rows that match your `WHERE` criteria. (Note that most databases are case-sensitive, so `kabol` is not equal to `Kabol`; the first would match your `WHERE`, but the second would not.)

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows one database row where `district` is `'Kabol'` (uppercase K), but your SQL query is looking for `'kabol'` (lowercase k) instead.  Assuming the query is comparing strins case-sensitively, that would explain why no row is found.  So either fix the case in your query input, or else perform a case-insensitive query instead.

Comment: I said that 4 hours ago (see the last paragraph of my answer). :-)